# py2app dependency problem

Tags: python, macos, py2app

i will create a OS X Package using py2app. It is a Game using the FIFE-Engine.
If i launch the resulting .app Bundle on another Mac i get this error Message:

> Failed to load FIFE: dlopen([...]/Contents/Resources/fife/engine/python/fife/_fife.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libSDL_ttf-2.0.0.dylib
>
> Referenced from: [...]/Contents/Resources/fife/engine/python/fife/_fife.so
> Reason: Incompatible library version: _fife.so requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libSDL_ttf-2.0.0.dylib provides version 7.0.0

but libSDL_ttf-2.0.0.dylib is included in the Frameworks dir of the .app

how can i tell the app to use the dylibs in the Frameworks folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it sounds related to the problem being discussed here: [py2app built app displays `ERROR: pygame.macosx import FAILED` on other machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201133/py2app-built-app-displays-error-pygame-macosx-import-failed-on-other-machines/6720996#6720996)

In particular, notice the one-line dynlib bug fix to boot_app.py (part of the py2app source).